# There is no any data showing into foreign key column

Tags: android, sqlite

[TABLE_BLOCKED_SMS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQBdW.png) , [TABLE_BLOCK_LIST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYD6S.png)
I have two tables which structure you can display in pictures. I made this table with below sqlite statements. The problem is when i add some data the foreign key named(fk_id_block_list) in TABLE_BLOCKED_SMS shown no any data but it should show ids of id_block_list column from TABLE_BLOCK_LIST. kindly help.

TABLE_BLOCKED_SMS

```
public static final String CREATE_TABLE_BLOCKED_SMS = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_BLOCKED_SMS
            + "(" + ID_BLOCKED_SMS + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT DEFAULT 0, "
            + MESSAGE_BODY + " TEXT,"
            + FK_ID_BLOCK_LIST + " INTEGER," +
            "FOREIGN KEY(" + FK_ID_BLOCK_LIST + ") REFERENCES " + TABLE_BLOCK_LIST + "(" + ID_BLOCK_LIST +"))";
```

TABLE_BLOCK_LIST:

```
public static final String CREATE_TABLE_BLOCK_LIST = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_BLOCK_LIST
            + "(" + ID_BLOCK_LIST + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT DEFAULT 0,"
            + ORIGINATING_ADDRESS + " TEXT)";
```

insert code:

```
 public boolean insertToBlockList(String originatingAddress,String messageBody){
        try {
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues value_TABLE_BLOCK_LIST = new ContentValues();
            ContentValues value_TABLE_BLOCKED_SMS = new ContentValues();

            value_TABLE_BLOCK_LIST.put(ORIGINATING_ADDRESS, originatingAddress);
            db.insert(TABLE_BLOCK_LIST, null, value_TABLE_BLOCK_LIST);

            value_TABLE_BLOCKED_SMS.put(MESSAGE_BODY, messageBody);
            db.insert(TABLE_BLOCKED_SMS, null, value_TABLE_BLOCKED_SMS);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Insertion to Block list", " error is" + e.getMessage());
        }
        return true;
    }
```

delete code:

```
 public int delete(long id){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return db.delete(TABLE_BLOCK_LIST, ID_BLOCK_LIST + " = ?", new String[]{Long.toString(id)});
    }
```

Comment: can you post your insert code? do you also insert something into TABLE_BLOCK_LIST so FK_ID_BLOCK_LIST points to an existing record?

Comment: i've posted please see now @MaximBerezovsky

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't linked the ID of `TABLE_BLOCK_LIST` with foreign key of `TABLE_BLOCKED_SMS`

You probably need to modify your codes to look like the following statements:

```
        value_TABLE_BLOCK_LIST.put(ORIGINATING_ADDRESS, originatingAddress);
        long insertId = db.insert(TABLE_BLOCK_LIST, null, value_TABLE_BLOCK_LIST);

        value_TABLE_BLOCKED_SMS.put(MESSAGE_BODY, messageBody);
        value_TABLE_BLOCKED_SMS.put(FK_ID_BLOCK_LIST, insertId);
        db.insert(TABLE_BLOCKED_SMS, null, value_TABLE_BLOCKED_SMS);
```

One other note on the semantics of your code:

I assume that you have block list and you want to link blocked messages to your blocked list. What you are doing in your code is creating a separate entry in your `TABLE_BLOCK_LIST` table without confirming that if a relevant entry exists or not. I suggest to check the existence of the record before trying to insert a new one in your table. For example executing the following `SQL` first:

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT "+ID_BLOCK_LIST+" FROM "+TABLE_BLOCK_LIST+" WHERE "+ORIGINATING_ADDRESS+"=?",new String[] {originatingAddress});
```

Comment: also please tell me how to delete data from TABLE_BLOCK_LIST as well as all reference via foreign key from TABLE_BLOCKED_SMS. @Pooya

Comment: my delete code cant able to delete foreign key reference data from TABLE_BLOCKED_SMS please help @Pooya

Comment: @bc120201817ZohaibSiddiq you need first delete all records in BLOCKED_SMS with the corresponding ID and then delete from BLOCK_LIST. This should be done explicitly by you

Comment: then what is the benefit of foreign key? I mean delete from BLOCK_LIST data should also delete from BLOCKED_SMS. its the benefit of foreign key @Pooya

Comment: @bc120201817ZohaibSiddiq the benefit of foreign key is when you want to query two tables and want a JOIN between two tables for the result

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/mysql-foreign-keys-quicker-database-development/ in this tutorial foreign key is use for deleting all references. please see @Pooya

Comment: @bc120201817ZohaibSiddiq That is correct but pay attention how it defined in the tutorial, it has two lines at the end ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE which you didn't include in your table definition

Comment: is it the correct syntex FOREIGN KEY(" + FK_ID_BLOCK_LIST + ") REFERENCES " + TABLE_BLOCK_LIST + "(" + ID_BLOCK_LIST +" ON DELETE CASCADE))";    @Pooya

Comment: @bc120201817ZohaibSiddiq Looks good here but check it in your app

Comment: dose not work FOREIGN KEY(" + FK_ID_BLOCK_LIST + ") REFERENCES " + TABLE_BLOCK_LIST
            + "(" + ID_BLOCK_LIST +" ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE))"; kindly suggust me any other tutorial like this. @Pooya

Comment: @bc120201817ZohaibSiddiq You missed the close parentheses before ON UPDATE ... , double check parentheses in your code

Comment: its also not working FOREIGN KEY(" + FK_ID_BLOCK_LIST + ") REFERENCES " + TABLE_BLOCK_LIST
            + "(" + ID_BLOCK_LIST +")" + " ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE";  @Pooya

Comment: if again syntax error then please please edit and post @Pooya

Answer (score 0):

`value_TABLE_BLOCK_LIST.put(ORIGINATING_ADDRESS, originatingAddress);
            db.insert(TABLE_BLOCK_LIST, null, value_TABLE_BLOCK_LIST);`

`db.insert` returns `long id` which is your primary key for inserted records. I guess you have to pass this key as foreign key value to your `value_TABLE_BLOCKED_SMS` under `FK_ID_BLOCK_LIST` key first before inserting it into `TABLE_BLOCKED_SMS`.

Also i'd recommend you to get familiar with using `insertWithOnConflict()` method rather then using simply `insert()`

Comment: also please tell me how to delete data from TABLE_BLOCK_LIST as well as all reference via foreign key from TABLE_BLOCKED_SMS. delete code posted. @Maxim Berezovsky